UVW Box mapping modifier (3dsmax) alternative in Blender
in 3dsMax very often I was using UVW Box Mapping modifier. It let me control the scale of the texture on each side of the box, no matter how much I have modified it earlier.
How to achieve it in Blender? I don't care about the corners. I just want to project some box mapping and be able to control texture scale and offset as I did in simple way in 3dsMax.
